# Beamer theme Metropolis changes TikZ draw

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots, beamer-metropolis

I am having trouble adding a TikZ graphic to my Beamer presentation which uses the theme Metropolis. Here is an example of the issue:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%\usetheme{metropolis}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        view = {135}{20},
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        zlabel=$z$,
        xmin=-1, xmax=1,
        ymin=-1, ymax=1,
        zmin=0, zmax=1,
    ]
    \draw (0, 1, 0) -- (1, 1, 1);
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This code does what I want, but uncommenting the line `\usetheme{metropolis}` changes the graphic and makes the line shorter. (I don't think it's invisible, just a very small length.) How can I get the desired image while still using the Metropolis theme?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The solution here seems to work: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579869/beamer-metropolis-theme-clashes-with-tikz-removes-content-from-tikzpicture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compile log shows PGFPlots

> Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true':
> you might b enefit from \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} (current compat
> level: 1.9).

Even though you have `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}`. The 1.9 level is hardcoded in the `metropolis` theme.

PGFPlots introduced `axis cs:` as the default coordinate system in version 1.11. One way is to keep using version 1.9 and give the coordinate system explicitly like this:

```
\draw (axis cs:0, 1, 0) -- (axis cs:1, 1, 1);
```

an other probably better way is to move `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}` inside `\begin{document}` like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        view = {135}{20},
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        zlabel=$z$,
        xmin=-1, xmax=1,
        ymin=-1, ymax=1,
        zmin=0, zmax=1,
    ]
    \draw (0, 1, 0) -- (1, 1, 1);
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

-or you could edit line 913 in the theme to correct the version.